# How to boot windows 7 after installing ubuntu 12.10 alongside?

Tags: boot, 12.10, grub2

I'm new to linux and am interested in learning it so I installed ubuntu 12.10 yesterday. Installation went smoothly and I chose "install alongside windows" option and I set about 50 gb using that slider and I thought I used 50 gb from c: drive but to my shock it used 50 gb space from f: drive. This was my first shock.

When I restarted and tried to log into windows, nothing happened except a black screen appeared saying "To restart press alt+ctrl+delete" but even pressing that it wont restart. No matter how many times I try rebooting, windows is not booting; same black screen saying restart appears. But I can log in to ubuntu and I can see that windows c: drive is fine.

Comment: Perhaps it might be helpful if you can copy and paste:
1) the grub menu entry for Windows 7 in file /boot/grub/grub.cfg
2) the UUID list of your drives, i.e. the output of this terminal command:
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
Also indicating which is your Windows drive (e.g. sda1, sda2, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case grub was not configured properly, try updating the grub boot menu.  Open a terminal window and type the command

sudo update-grub

Comment: Thanks for the tip! but I already tried that its not working

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when organizing/resizing partitions during installation, may be your partition table changed and windows7 bootloader now pointing to a partition without windows.

Boot with Widnows 7 installation disc and make **startup repair**.

Comment: I recovered windows 7 using the  bootrec.exe /FixBoot and installed EasyBCD to dual boot. Its fixed now :) Thanks for the help guys!!